# Error: Installing and using Mariadb on Docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu, mariadb

I am running this command:

```
docker run --net mynet --ip IP -p 3306:3306 --mount source=database,target=/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=XXXX mariadb:10.5.17
```

I get the following error:

[Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt0sM.png)

When I google, I find that I have to remove certain log files and run the following commands:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile*
```

And then retry, but I get the same error repeatedly. Does anyone have a clue what am I missing here?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I bet you didn't find that in the official documentation. Did you find all the people that said don't delete `ib_logfile*`, because I did an lost everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
docker volume rm database
```

You need to also delete the volume on the host. Otherwise everytime you restart the container it will pickup an existing setup.

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT ever do anything so fatal to your data as `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile*`. Only follow guides of official documentation when doing anything that involved directly touching database files.

The error in your log is "redo log created with MariaDB-10.8.2". The log formats aren't backwards compatible and you are starting with MariaDB-10.5.17 which is why it fails to initialize.

So either start with a MariaDB-10.8.2+ container image, or reinitiaize by removing the entire volume data like what Mihai answered.